# Python - Calculate last quarter hour of current time

Tags: python, datetime

How do I round the time to last quarter hour for the current time. I am able to find the last quarter hour minute, however, not able to fit this into the correct time format.

```
import datetime
import time

time = datetime.datetime.now()
last_quarter_minute = 15*(time.minute//15)

current_time = time.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M")

print last_quarter_minute
print current_time
```

Ideally, I want to be able to compare the time I get from a log, to the last quarter time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to replace `minute` part of the `time`, using [`datetime.datetime.replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace) (returns a new datetime object with the specifieid field replaced):

```
>>> time.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M")
'2016/05/13 12:57'
>>> time.replace(minute=last_quarter_minute).strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M")
'2016/05/13 12:45'
```

To be more precise, you need to also set `second`, `microsecond` also.

Comment: Thank you, can I compare '2016/05/13 12:45' with an similar format output

Comment: I think I have got it, thank you! if current_time > last_quarter:
    print "True"